# Android material design drop-down layout issue when array list added

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, material-design

I am facing some issue's with android material design drop-down menu items. Below are my issues with code and images. I implemented material design drop-down menu items and earlier the layout was absolutely fine. but after adding the array-list my layout width automatically get increased. below is mine code:

XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:hint="Product Category"
                    app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu"
                    app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/productCategoryDropdown"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1.115"
                        android:hint="Product Weight"
                        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="65dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.9"
                        android:hint="Weight Unit"
                        app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu"
                        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

                        <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:id="@+id/productWeightUnitDropdown"
                            android:paddingStart="5dp"
                            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"/>

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
```

My Layout after XML:

[image]

Java code for same:

```
Dropdown = view.findViewById(R.id.productWeightUnitDropdown);

        String[] weightUnit = new String[] {
                "kg (Kilogram)",
                "pcs (Piece)"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> weightUnitAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.dropdown_item,
                weightUnit
        );

        weightUnitDropdown.setAdapter(weightUnitAdapter);
```

Drop-Down Item.XML

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1">
</TextView>
```

After adding the java code width of the weight unit drop-down layout automatically increased. and now my layout looks like this. Not understanding why alignment gets disturbed.:

[image]

Also please help why in product category layout my selected item is coming over the hint. why it's not taking equal spacing like edit-text. The same issue is with the weight unit layout also. Compare product weight text and weight unit text, not in the same alignment. also, my keyboard opens when I click on this drop-down. I don't want a keyboard in this.

Comment: Try `android:singleLine="true"` in the textview xml
Although it's deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue and as [the documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-fields#using-text-fields) explains, you better use a style in your `TextInputLayout` to achieve the right effects and behaviors for `ExposedDropdownMenus` as follows:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

And also for `TextInputLayout` with `TextInputEditText`:

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
```

Result:

[image]

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:hint="Product Category"
        app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu"
        app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/productCategoryDropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Product Weight"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Weight Unit"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/colorPrimary">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/productWeightUnitDropdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

P.S: No need to mention that it has some behavior issues with `AutoCompleteTextView` like when you tap on the widget, it show show the `DropDown` menus (and it shouldn't get any values and the like) which can be solved by a trick using `onFocusChangeListener` to tell when user tapped on the widget and has focus, hide the keyboard and make it to show only the list:

```
(state_layout.editText as AutoCompleteTextView).inputType = EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL
        state_layout.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _: View?, hasFocus ->
            if (hasFocus) {
                hideKeyboard(this)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was gonna write the exact same thing

Comment: Oh sorry, I was a bit quick :]. However, to make the answer complete, I've added the P.S section.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me one more thing.. by your code when Edit-Text is in focus the outline get invisible. I want that outline will always visible whether it's in focus or not.

Comment: It works fine on my side. Also, the kotlin code should be used only for the `AutoCompleteTextView`. Also, [take a look](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1141) Perhaps updating the material design dependency should help: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'` because of `OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu`.